# Conditional formatting to change whole section green when all checkmarks in section are ticked

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, conditional-formatting

Okay so I have a google sheets where there are multiple columns with multiple checkmarks. I want to make it so that when individual checkmarkes (B1:B4 and D1:D4 in example below) are checked, the corresponding cells gets turned green. When all checkmarks are checked, I want the whole section (A1:D4) to change from green to grey. So far, I've managed to turn each individual check green but am not sure how to turn a section grey, any help is super appreciated!

Im linking a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RFyrwlfAT9ofe_ky9A0vmhVu3dIjPeStk4JtmPKR2pQ/edit?usp=sharing) here for clarity.

I've tried using countif/counta but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

***Apply to range:***  `A1:D4`

***Custom formula is:***

```js
=countif({$B$1:$B$4;$D$1:$D$4},true)=8
```

[image]

- *Keep this rule above the `green` condition rules in the **conditional-formatting** list*